# Stretch the wpf tab control content

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to stretch the wpf tab control content for fit the screen when it resizes even if the tab item is empty. There doesnt seem to be a stretch property?

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [edit] I was trying to dispaly it is using text but cant

Comment: When I resize the window the tab item where the content is display does not stretch to the bottom of the window. However it does to the sides not matter how big or small i make the window. I would like the same behaviour for the top to bottom

Comment: If you want to post code in a question or answer, you need to indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried the code below and the rectangle seemed to to stretch correctly.  The TabControl also stretched correctly if I removed the Border & Rectangle from the TabItem.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by 'empty,' but give this a try.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabItem Header="Item 1" Name="tabItem1">
            <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                <Rectangle Fill="Pink" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Border>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```